# Error occured while synchronizing xconnect contacts to salesforce

Tags: xconnect, data-exchange-framework, salesforce-connect, contact

I am using Sitecore XP 9.3 to synchronize contacts data from Sitecore to salesforce and vice versa.
For this, I installed the Sitecore Data Exchange framework 4.0 package and Sitecore connect for Salesforce CRM 4.0 . After did a set up , I ran the pipeline batch **xconnect contacts to salesforce sync** , it throws the error

> ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not
> saved:INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE* and
> *ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Event: bad field names on insert/update call: SitecoreId__c

[image]

Can anyone help to me fix this error?

While I ran the Pipeline batch **Salesforce contacts to Xconnect sync**, It's working fine.

I referred the below blog for do this.

https://varunvns.wordpress.com/2019/05/31/sitecore-salesforce-setting-up-salesforce-connect/

https://varunvns.wordpress.com/2019/06/22/sitecore-salesforce-connecting-sitecore-contacts-with-salesforce-contacts/

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above issue, I raised the ticket in Sitecore support portal. Here is the response of the above issue from sitecore support portal. It works fine for me.

Please ensure that you had created "**Sitecore Id**" field in your Salesforce as it describes in chapter 1.5. "Add a custom field in Salesforce (optional)" of the installation guide?
[https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/630DFC39E8F34EB1965624783D1701F9.ashx?date=20200825T102007](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/630DFC39E8F34EB1965624783D1701F9.ashx?date=20200825T102007)

Also please ensure that the salesforce user which is used for Sitecore connection has permissions to create and edit contacts and all contacts fields.
As far as I see, such an error can also occur when the user hasn't rights to edit the field.

Please check that salesforce user has appropriate rights to edit Sitecore Id field - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/users_profiles_field_perms.htm